# Find all natural numbers $a,b$ such that $b^a|(a^b-1)$

Tags: number-theory

Find all natural numbers $a,b$ such that
$$b^a|(a^b-1)$$

I tried it in this method

Let $a>b$ and $b|a$. $a=pb$

$$(p.b)^b-1=b^{p.b}$$

or,$$b^b(p^b-b^{b(p-1)})=1
\\b^b|1,b=1$$

So two solutions are $(a,1),(1,b)$
So it is clear that $\gcd(a,b)=1$.
I thought of trying $a=pk+b$ but can't do further.

Comment: You're apparently only missing one solution and the proof.  See, e.g., https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2044784p14482940

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If you are "first to MSE", then please first inform yourself how this site works. First, please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Secondly, try to improve your title.

Comment: There is [lot of solutions](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24b%5Ea%7Ca%5Eb-1%24&p=1) using LTE.